# Htaccess RewriteRule not working while it should

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

After a bit of googling I think I have a .htaccess file that should work.
The idea is fairly simple, if the thing after the domain.com/ exists it should show it, else it does a rewrite to index.php?p=.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.* - [L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/ index.php?p=$1
```

Now when i go to domain.com/hello , i get an error that the directory 'hello' doesn't exist..
The htaccess file is being used during the request though because when I putt something in the htaccess code that shouldn't work, it gives an error.

Can someone tell me what the problem might be?

I checked the apache config and mod_rewrite is enabled.

thanks,
Robin

Comment: Where is your files placed is it in root or any sub directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please define Rewrite base in your htaccess if its placed on root directory

```
RewriteBase /
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't write the first slash on RewriteRule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/ index.php?p=$1
```

It should work this way

EDIT: Try this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Added that, but it didn't change anything, still giving the error the the requested directory doesnt exist.
Then I changed it to 
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php?p=$1

Now it says that /public_html/index.php doesn't exist.. while it does.

Comment: 404 cant find the requested dir

Comment: Change this /index.php/$1 to this /index.php?p=$1

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/ index.php?p=$1
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/? index.php?p=$1
```

Comment: It tries to load index.php now, but it gives an error that index.php can't be found.. while it does exist in the directory where the system is looking for it.

Could it be something that im currently using the temp. url server.ext/~user/ instead of the full domain?